# setstate cannot update during an state transition - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change image source `url from it's child component. If they clicks on button1 index 0 of backgroundImages`array` will be the image source. button2 will be index 1, button 3 will be index 2.

But it is showing setstate cannot update during an existing state transition.

Below I'm attaching code.

> App.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ChildComponent = require('./child-component.jsx');

var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return{
      backgroundImage: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464013778555-8e723c2f01f8?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=4b2c415f63f63afa66a347f993351bee'
    };
  },
  handleBackgroundChange: function(imageIndex) {
    this.setState({
      backgroundImage: this.backgrounds[imageIndex]
    });
  },
  backgrounds: [
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464013778555-8e723c2f01f8?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=4b2c415f63f63afa66a347f993351bee',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463595373836-6e0b0a8ee322?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=69a198dc9bfba968b5deb20c04cec8c9',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462819067004-905a72ea3996?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=4832f28a526c7a3538a887b8fbbfe897'
  ],
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <img src={this.state.backgroundImage} height="400px" width="400px"/>
        <ChildComponent handleBackgroundChange = {this.handleBackgroundChange}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var element = React.createElement(Hello, {});
ReactDOM.render(element, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

> child-component.jsx

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  handleBackgroundChange: function(imageIndex){
    this.props.handleBackgroundChange(imageIndex);
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick = {this.handleBackgroundChange(0)}>Image 1</button>
      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick = {this.handleBackgroundChange(1)}>Image 2</button>
      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick = {this.handleBackgroundChange(2)}>Image 3</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

As per my knowledge I didn't use any illegal state transitions or `setState()` method in the code. Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```
onClick = {this.handleBackgroundChange(0)}
```

You execute directly the function instead of giving his reference, try like this

```
onClick = {this.handleBackgroundChange.bind(this, 0)}
```

Comment: This suggestion is not giving any error. **Thank you, But main problem is the image is not being changed.** but `this.state.backgroundImage` is changing.

Comment: Sorry for the earlier reply. This is working fine. But the thing is that my network is slow. The image is being changed after loading the complete image. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issues too and i did it (stole from a colleague's code) like  `const handleBackgroundChange = () => this.handleBackgroundChange(0)` not needing to `bind()`.